# Assert with string argument not working as expected

Tags: objective-c, assert

EDIT:  The issue was with the assert as people pointed out below.  Thanks for the help!

I have a enum set that i'm trying equate, but for some reason its not working.
Its declared like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ExUnitTypes) {
    kuNilWorkUnit,
    kuDistanceInMeters,
    //end
    kuUndefined
};
```

And i'm using it here:

```
  +(NSString*) ExUnitDescription: (ExUnitTypes) exUnit
{
    if (exUnit == kuNilWorkUnit)
    {
        assert("error with units");
    }
///.... more stuff
}
```

Xcode isnt triggering my assert.  EDIT:  the assert is just for testing.  i've used NSLog as well.  The conditional isn't evaluating to true even though the value is clearly kuNilWorkUnit.

[image: xcode enum asser image]

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you are using assert instead of NSAssert?

Comment: It's not Xcode that triggers the assert. It's the condition evaluating to `false` or `0` and the `assert()` macro. Anyway, a string literal will never decay into a `NULL` pointer, so the assertion `assert("arbitrary string literal here");` will never fire. You will now need to read the documentation of `assert()` to realize what's wrong and how to solve it. Further recommended stuff to read (**carefully**): `man 3 abort`, `man 3 exit` and a good tutorial on the `if` statement in C.

Comment: I'm just using the assert to test this issue.  i can switch to nsassert or NSLog or whatever.  The condition isn't evaluating to true even though my variable is clearly kuNilWorkUnit.

Comment: @ShravanSunder The condition **does** evaluate to true. It's just `"error with units"` that doesn't evaluate to *false*.

Comment: Yes you guys are right.  I shouldn't be using assert().  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
+(NSString*) ExUnitDescription: (ExUnitTypes) exUnit
{
    assert(exUnit != kuNilWorkUnit);

    ///.... more stuff
}
```

This is because, `assert` only stops execution if the expression you pass to it is false. Since a string literal is always non-zero, it will never stop execution.

Now, since you are using Objective C and it also looks like you want to have a message associated with your assert, NSAssert would be preferable.

```
+(NSString*) ExUnitDescription: (ExUnitTypes) exUnit
{
    NSAssert(exUnit != kuNilWorkUnit, @"error with units");

    ///.... more stuff
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to promote `NSAssert` over `assert` in Cocoa code.